# Reduce number of times an event gets fired? [bad/incorrect title - change if you have a better one]

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

```
var time = null;
var bounds = null;
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'bounds_changed',function(){
    bounds = map.getBounds();
    time = (new Date()).getTime();
    setTimeout(function(){
        var now = ((new Date()).getTime() - 999);
        if(now > time){
            console.log('now: '+now+ ' then: '+time+ ' diff: '+(now-time));
            // here I want to fire an event exactly 1 time instead of a baizllion
            alert('I just want to see this once after the map was moved');
        }
    },1000);
});
```

Basically when the map changes the bounds_changed seems to trigger quite a lot.
I thought that if I declare time outside it would be overwritten. Maybe wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only dragging the map, have you tried the **dragend** event?

Otherwise, I think the use of a **shared Timer** is a common way to overcome this. You probably have the right idea reading your code snippet.

Every trigger of the **bounds_changed** event resets the timer, when time's up, the timer triggers your desired function. You just need to move the timer out and share it amongs all the **bounds_changed** events.

[the APIv3 link](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html)

**Updates**

You can try:

```
    function fireEvent()
    {
        if (lastEvent.getTime() + 500 <= new Date().getTime())
        {
            //your event
        }
    }

    function DelayedCallback()
    {
        lastEvent = new Date();
        setTimeout(fireEvent, 500);
    }
event.addListener(map, "bounds_changed", DelayedCallback);
```

taken from [here](http://www.webusadlp8.appspot.com/V1RJNWExcFROVzVpTWpsdVlrZFZkVmt5T1hSTU0wRjJXakl4YUdOSVRYUlpXRUp3VEZkc2VtTXpWbXhqZVRsd1l6Tk9NVnBZVFhaYVIxWXdXVmRzYzFBeWJHdFFWRVY2VG5wRlBRPT0=)

Comment: dragend triggers 8 times (much less than the bounds_changed) yes, i thought I could use a shared timer, but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also dragend does not trigger changes on zoom :(

Comment: Thanks, this is a clearer way. I figured why it triggered 8 times, it's because I had 8 markers that trigger map.fitBounds(bounds);

Comment: in general, it is hard to know how many times bounds_changed might be triggered, so it is safer to wrap it with a timer.